# How to change the layout of a quantile regression summary graph?

Tags: r, regression, quantile

I have done a quantile regression on electricity prices for a school project. The regression equation is as follows:

```
Regression_EPEX <- rq(EPEX$`Day-Ahead Price` ~ EPEX$lagged_day + EPEX$lagged_week + 
EPEX$`Load    [MWh]` + EPEX$`Wind total` + EPEX$`Solar (PV) [MWh]` + EPEX$`Wind share` + EPEX$`Solar Share`,
tau=seq(0.1,0.9, by = 0.1), data=EPEX)
```

I have plotted the graph via:

```r
Regression_EPEX_plot <- summary(Regression_EPEX)

plot(Regression_EPEX_plot)
```

I want to modify the colors of the quantile regression as well as the ols regression. I also want to modify the limits of the axis